# matplotlib custom marker, empty or filled circle with plus sign inside

Tags: python, matplotlib, markers

I am trying to make a simple plot in matplotlib with custom marker. I am looking for a marker that looks like an empty or filled circle with plus sign that extends from inside to outside[image]. Also I want to set a custom (bigger than default) marker size. This marker is necessary to present the data. I am attaching my code here:

```
import sys
import os
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *


trap_error = 'mag_velocity.txt'

mag, vel = numpy.loadtxt(trap_error, unpack =True)

#plt.plot(vel, mag, '\\bigoplus')
plt.plot(vel, mag, marker='$\\bigoplus$', markersize=15)     
plt.ylim(-11, -19)
plt.xlim(-2, -7)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I looked into internet and I thought '\bigoplus' is what I am looking for, but it seems not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use '\bigoplus', you should to include it in `$...$` which causes the string to be rendered by mathtext (like latex).  See [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) for details on matplotlib markers.

If you want to increase the marker size, use `markersize`.  For example, try this:

```
plt.plot(vel, mag, marker='$\\bigoplus$', markersize=10, linestyle='None')
```

Comment: thanks @Douglas, If I do that, my plot makes a line plot instead of scatter markers, please  see the updated image below. plt.scatter returns me some error, can you please tell me how to make it a mrker only plot?

Comment: Good point, add `linestyle='None'` to remove the line.    I've updated the answer too.